Regarding existence of algebraic closure
In Lang's Algebra after proving the existence of a algebraically closed field extension, he then proceeds to consider the union of all algebraic subextensions of this algebraically closed field over the base field and proves that that union is algebraically closed. Hence we have an algebraic closure. My question : isn't the object $E = \cup_{i>0} E_{i}$ defined in the proof not an algebraic extension itself and thus an algebraic closure? If so, I am not sure how the proof would go.

Theorem 2.5. Let $k$ be a field. Then there exists an algebraically closed field containing $k$ as a subfield.
Proof. We first construct an extension $E_1$ of $k$ in which every polynomial in $k[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$ has a root. One can proceed as follows (Artin). To each polynomial $f\in k[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$ we associate a letter $X_f$ and we let $S$ be the set of all such letters $X_f$ (so that $S$ is in bijection with the set of polynomials in $k[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$). We form the polynomial ring $k[S]$, and contend that the ideal generated by all the polynomials $f(X_f)$ in $k[S]$ is not the unit ideal. If it is, then there is a finite combination of elements in our ideal which is equal to $1$:
$$g_1f_1(X_{f_1}) + \cdots + g_nf_n(X_{f_n}) = 1$$
with $g_i\in k[S]$. For simplicity, write $X_i$ instead of $X_{f_i}$. The polynomials $g_i$ will involve actually only a finite number of variables, say $X_1,\ldots,X_{N}$ (with $N\geq n$). Ourr relation then reads
$$\sum_{i=1}^ng_i(X_1,\ldots,X_N)f_i(X_i) = 1.$$
Let $F$ be the finite extension in which each polynomial $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ has a root, say $\alpha_i$ is a root of $f_i$ in $F$, for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Let $\alpha_i=0$ for $i\gt n$. Substitute $\alpha_i$ for $X_i$ in our relation. We get $0=1$, a contradiction.
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal containing the ideal generated by all polynoials $f(X_f)$ in $k[S]$. Then $k[S]/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, and we have a canonical map $$\sigma\colon k[S]\to k[S]/\mathfrak{m}.$$
For any polynomial $f\in k[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$, the polynomial $f^{\sigma}$ has a root in $k[S]/\mathfrak{m}$, which is an extension of $\sigma k$. Using the same type of set-theoretic argument as in Proposition 2.3, we conclude that exists an extension $E_1$ of $k$ in which every polynomial $f\in k[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$ has a root in $E_1$.
Inductively, we can form a sequence of fields
$$E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3\subset\cdots\subset E_n\cdots$$
such that every polynomial in $E_n[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$ has a root in $E_{n+1}$. Let $E$ be the union of all fields $E_{n}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then $E$ is naturally a field [...]
[...]
Every polynomial in $E[X]$ has coefficients in some subfield $E_n$, hence a root in $E_{n+1}$, hence a root in $E$, as desired.


The intersection is $E_1$, you mean the union?

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is an explanation of why.

I shall take care of that in the future. Thanks

You are correct that the extension constructed in the proof is algebraic.
To prove this, it suffices to show that each $E_i$ is algebraic over $k$. To see this, we first note $E_{i + 1}$ is algebraic over $E_i$, which is because the generators $X_f$ are algebraic. Then by induction, $E_i$ is algebraic over $k$ for each $i$, as $E_{i + 1} / E_i / k$ consists of a pair of algebraic extensions.
